# SQL large CASE vs. JOIN efficiency on a large SELECT output

Tags: sql-server

I work with a fairly unoptomized database- performance varies daily so I would like to make my output as quick as possible.  I was hoping to figure out the most efficient way to append values to my output. With most sets, I have to export fairly wide final dimensions (upwards of 20-60 columns, 60-500k rows), so processing has to be accounted for as well. Benchmarking is a little tricky on this, because it seems to vary with server load.

So, join on a large table, vs appending with a long CASE argument- both seem ungainly, but whats the best course of action?

Example:

--Entity Table output would result 250k  rows, 50 col
--Entity Types Table has 1k rows, 2 col (key and description)

```
select e.*, et.description 
from Entities e  
inner join entity_types et ON e.entity_type_key = et.entity_type_key;
```

~or~

```
select e.* 
case 
when e.entity_type_key = 1 then 'Description 1 from entity_types'
when e.entity_type_key = 2 then 'Description 2 from entity_types'
(repeat about 1k times)..

from Entities e
```

Comment: A Join is the "natural" way to do it, and it would be far more efficient, and much easier to write and maintain.

Comment: The best way to answer these questions yourself, beyond just looking at the plans, is to use "SET STATISTICS TIME ON" before the query, and "SET STATISTICS TIME OFF" after, and then read the dump of statistics. Also look at "SET STATISTICS IO ON" and "SET STATISTICS IO OFF" to look at I/O metrics. You can see the exact data and compare apples to apples, using your real data on your own physical hardware.

Comment: Join is the better way to do this... What happens if in future your Entity_Types added or changed more types? Do you change code for this statement?

Comment: The average person blinks around 1,000 times per hour.  That's enough repetition for me.

Comment: @pmb - I previously noted, benchmarking doesn't do much good in this case. The server this particular dataset on really really varies from day to day- it's a really wonky server we don't have much control over. (as in, a simple query can take anywhere from .002 seconds to execute to 5 minutes ). But I guess Set Statistics would make a nice weather report...

Comment: @ zohar @ Kann - I figured join was natural, entity_types is on something that is a fixed-coded dataset (laws & buildings would have to move and change).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular case you will not see a big difference. Table will be cached (probably) and lookup will be very fast (and we can assume that table is very small). Case statement requires slightly more time for parsing (some nanoseconds, I don't know) and slightly more network traffic but... again, I don't think you should think about it at all.

You can even map it on the application layer. Or just use join because it is more configurable and more readable.

Comment: Thanks! I am a bit worried about network traffic as eventually I would like to automate some of my datafeeds on a few projects. So to clarify, your saying that the joined table will be cached?